# mysql group by and order by does not work

Tags: mysql, database, group-by

I have a question, if you can help me please ?

I'm using the "group by" and "order by", but the order by does not work
I want to get the last element of a group that got the same value in a column
Here is my query
`$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages GROUP BY id_sender ORDER BY message_time");`

`messages`
`id | sender | receiver | message_time | id_sender`
`1 | Joe | Mellen | 05-01-30 | 1`
`2 | Joe | Mellen | 04-01-31 | 1`
`3 | balbal | blabla | 05-01-30 | 2`
`4 | balbal | blabla | 15-31-20 | 2`
 
I want to get something like
`Joe Mellen / 04-01-31`
`balbal blabla / 15-31-20`

Comment: You are not using `GROUP BY` correctly. Can you clarify the result you want? It looks like you want the row with the greatest `id` per `sender/receiver` group.  Is that correct? For that, you'll need a `MAX()` aggregate and a subquery join...

Comment: Yeah that's right, I want to get the highest id where id_sender is the same

Comment: If you have a full solution, feel free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for something like this after reading your extra comments:

```
select m.* 
from messages m
  join ( 
    select id_sender, max(id) maxid
    from messages
    group by id_sender
    ) t on m.id = t.maxid
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4d18/3)

Basically you need to use a subquery to determine the `max()` of each id for each id_sender, and then join back to the original table.